# network boot options hosted on Windows (XP or 7)

Tags: windows

I'm looking to setup a quick and dirty network boot server to install XP on a beatup laptop that has a bad CDROM but the option to "network boot"  (Compaq pasario 700)

1) what is the difference between pxe and Ris

2) which one is most likely to be the one used on the laptop mentioned above

3) is there a Windows program to run a boot server

4) what files will I need to have can I jut use the CD or do I need to rip it to files or and ISO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to install WinXP/Windows7 from a USB flash drive / USB hard drive.

There are [various tools](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=install+windows+7+from+usb) to help simplify/automate the setting up of the usb device to be used as a boot source. Hope this helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As I know about RIS. It is pack of tools including tftp server purposed for windows automated installation.

PXE boot require DHCP options, 66 point to TFTP server and 67 boot image name. And boot image located on TFTP server.

I make by that way boot of diagnostic and recovery tools.